# Making AutoIT wait until Audacity completes command

Tags: autoit, audacity

I have a script that I'd like to use to automate processes in Audacity. I have it set up so that all the functions I want to do in Audacity are keyboard shortcuts (since I don't think Audacity uses standard window menus like is required for `WinMenuSelectItem()`) In other words, my whole code consists of multiple instances of the `Send()` command. The problem is, AutoIT executes the code too fast. I've tried using `WinWait()`, but the processes take variable amounts of time. I've also tried `ShellExecuteWait()` and `RunWait()`Is there a way to get it to wait until the program isn't doing something, and then execute my send commands? Here's some of my code

```
Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Audacity\audacity.exe")
; wait until it's active
WinWaitActive("Audacity")

; get the dialogue box to go away
Send("{ENTER}")
RunWait("Audacity")

; open files
Send("^o")
RunWait("Audacity")

; open the certain file & press enter
Send("test.wav")
RunWait("Audacity")
Send("{ENTER}")
RunWait("Audacity")

; select left boundary of silence period
Send("[")
RunWait("Audacity")
Send("000000100{ENTER}")
RunWait("Audacity")

; select right boundary of silence period
Send("]")
RunWait("Audacity")
Send("200000000{ENTER}")
RunWait("Audacity")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
; Use for debugging issues. Systray icon show current line.
Opt('TrayIconDebug', 1)

; Delay default: 250s
Opt('WinWaitDelay', 400)

; Delay default: 5s
Opt('SendKeyDelay', 100)

; Path of the wav file.
$sInFile = @WorkingDir & '\test.wav'

; Optional permanent change of splash screen setting.
_SplashScreen(True)

; Run Audacity and argument of the wav file.
$iPid = Run('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Audacity\audacity.exe" "' & $sInFile & '"')

; Check if Run Audacity failed.
If @error Then
    MsgBox(0x40030, @ScriptName, 'Failed to run Audacity')
    Exit 1
EndIf

; Wait for main window to get handle. Title is the filename with no extension.
$hMainWindow = WinWait('[TITLE:test; CLASS:wxWindowNR]', '', 10)

; Check allowed timeout of window.
If Not $hMainWindow Then
    MsgBox(0x40030, @ScriptName, 'Audacity window not detected.')
    Exit 1
EndIf

; If splash screen setting not 0 then handle the window.
If _SplashScreen() Then
    AdlibRegister('_WelcomeWindow')
    WinWait('Welcome to Audacity', '', 3)
    AdlibUnRegister('_WelcomeWindow')
EndIf

; Send '[' to main window to trigger Left Boundary window.
ControlSend($hMainWindow, '', '', '[')

; Get handle of Left Boundary window.
$hMsgWindow = WinWait('Set Left Selection Boundary', '', 5)

; Check allowed timeout of window.
If Not $hMsgWindow Then
    MsgBox(0x40030, @ScriptName, 'Selection Boundary window not detected.')
    Exit 1
EndIf

; Activate window, set time and click OK.
If WinActivate($hMsgWindow) Then
    ControlSend($hMsgWindow, '', 'wxWindowNR1', '{LEFT 3}1'); 1000
    ControlClick($hMsgWindow, '', 'Button2'); OK
EndIf

; Send ']' to main window to trigger Right Boundary window.
ControlSend($hMainWindow, '', '', ']')

; Get handle of Right Boundary window.
$hMsgWindow = WinWait('Set Right Selection Boundary', '', 5)

; Check allowed timeout of window.
If Not $hMsgWindow Then
    MsgBox(0x40030, @ScriptName, 'Selection Boundary window not detected.')
    Exit 1
EndIf

; Activate window, set time and click OK.
If WinActivate($hMsgWindow) Then
    ; Audacity shows 1000 and focus is on the 1st non zero digit which is 1.
    ControlSend($hMsgWindow, '', 'wxWindowNR1', '2'); 2000
    ControlClick($hMsgWindow, '', 'Button2'); OK
EndIf

; More code to do.
Sleep(1000)

MsgBox(0x40040, @ScriptName, 'End of automation.' & @CRLF & @CRLF & _
     'You can close Audacity to finish.')

; Wait for Audacity process to close.
ProcessWaitClose($iPid)

Exit

Func _WelcomeWindow()
    ; Used by AdlibRegister to handle the Welcome window.

    ; Welcome window hides if closed so need to check if exist and is visible (2).
    If WinExists('Welcome to Audacity') Then
        If BitAND(WinGetState('Welcome to Audacity'), 2) Then
            WinClose('Welcome to Audacity')
        Else
            AdlibUnRegister('_WelcomeWindow')
        EndIf
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _SplashScreen($bDisable = False)
    ; Write to audacity.cfg to disable splash screen.
    Local $sIniFile = @AppDataDir & '\Audacity\audacity.cfg'

    If IniRead($sIniFile, 'GUI', 'ShowSplashScreen', '1') = '1' Then
        If $bDisable Then
            ; Return 1 if ini file change is success.
            If IniWrite($sIniFile, 'GUI', 'ShowSplashScreen', '0') Then
                Return 1
            EndIf
        Else
            ; Return 1 if check for splash screen is enabled.
            Return 1
        EndIf
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

`Opt()` is used to slow down the wait of windows and the sends.
Also added `Opt('TrayIconDebug', 1)` for debugging though if
the script is considered good then you can remove that `Opt()`.

`ControlSend()` is used instead of `Send()` as `ControlSend()`
targets windows and controls based of title, text, etc.
The `Opt()` delays are not required though was added to
demonstrate the usage, though perhaps Audacity may struggle
to keep with the speed that AutoIt can automate.
If possible, suggest use of `Control*()` functions for automation.

Storing window handles in a variable can help save retyping titles
in the code. `WinWait()` returns a window handle which is ideal and
if the timeout parameter is used, then 0 indicates the window not
found so automation can be aborted.

The Classname of the main window is not enough on its own as
Audacity creates many invisible windows with the same Classname.
So, the title may need to be used as well. The title could be
used alone though titled by filename may not be unique at times. 
See [Window Titles and Text Advanced](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm) for usage.

`WinActivate()` is used on the Boundary windows although it
may not be needed as `control*()` usually do not need active
windows. Standard Msgboxes in comparison may require to be
active to accept messages sent to them.

`ShellExecuteWait()` and `RunWait()` are no good for automation
as they block the script from continuing until the executed
process has finished.
So use `ShellExecute()` or `Run()` instead.
The repetitive use of `RunWait("Audacity")` seems like
desperation to correct the behavior perhaps, though flawed.
Waiting for windows to appear is how to control flow and then
functions such as `ControlCommand()` can detect state of controls.

`ControlClick()` is used on the buttons.
CtrlID of Classname `Button2` is used though if the script
is always for English users then you can use the text which
would be `OK` for the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

The `ProcessWaitClose($iPid)` is optional.
It is sometimes useful to wait for the program
being automated to exit before the script exits.

You comment "*get the dialogue box to go away*" in you code
after starting Audacity. You can change the setting on the
dialogue box or *Preferences -> Interface* options. Advice
disabling as it is a future problem to keep handling.
I added some code to disable the setting in the
`audacity.cfg` file. If not preferred to disable with
`_SplashScreen(True)` or done manually then
the `AdLibRegister('_WelcomeWindow')` call will handle
closing the window. Note that the Welcome window does
not close but rather hides.

`_SplashScreen(True)` changes splash setting to `0` to disable the splash.

`_SplashScreen(False)` or `_SplashScreen()` does no change of settings.
The call returns `1` if splash is enabled else `0`.